# WHere can i get the java advanced project specifications for students

Tags: java, projects-and-solutions

I searched on internet about java projects and found this link

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=11751&s=79d38d1783f39c95b42a9aac38d9e579

This is the student project with some specifications .

Is it possible to get some more like these i project with specifications so that it uses all concepts from various topics like in students assignments or projects

Answer (score 0):

You will find various project abstracts at [mcaprojects](http://mcaprojects.org/projectindex.php)

Also you can find on: [projectspeaks](http://www.projectspeaks.com/projects.html)

Try to [make your own project specification](http://www.packagingdigest.com/article/345743-How_to_Write_a_Project_Specification_Seven_Rules_that_Save_the_Day.php) it can be more better.

Hope this helps.